# How to get link with special word from webpage using selenium and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am working on a python script which aim is to get all links containing a certain word from a given webpage.

```
www.example.com/about/someone

www.example.com/profile/someone

www.example.com/about/someone2
```

So the code should get only those links which contains the word `about`.
I am getting the following error:

```
"AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get' "
```

And here is my code:

```
driver.get("http://example.com/mypage")
time.sleep(20)

links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for link in links:
  if '/about/' in link.get( 'href' ):
     print (link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: Use `if '/about/' in link.get_attribute('href')`

Comment: i get this error TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.get("http://example.com/mypage")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for link in links:
  href = link.get_attribute('href')

  if not href:
      continue

  if '/about/' in href:
     print(href)
```